# What does the `gen` option in bitcoin.conf do?

Tags: bitcoin-core, miner-configuration, bitcoin.conf

The `gen` option isnt copiously described in [the sample bitcoin.conf file](https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Running_Bitcoin#Bitcoin.conf_Configuration_File)  ... does that mean that the daemon started up will attempt to mine for coins?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

That configuration parameter no longer has any effect because the CPU mining engine has been removed from the mainline client.

Earlier versions of the client did have a built in miner and the gen parameter controlled if it ran in the background.  Given the much higher difficulty today the developers felt it no longer served a purpose and would be confusing to new users (who could wait months of even years without generating a single coin).  It was removed from the client.  The wiki should be updated to reflect that.

Comment: This is incorrect: the built in miner was removed from the GUI, but remains accessible in bitcoind.

Comment: Your answer is now correct. RIP internal miner (see https://github.com/bitcoin/bitcoin/pull/7507)

Answer (score 5):

*Bitcoin core executables (bitcoin-qt and bitcoind) cannot even attempt to mine real Bitcoin since 2016. At https://github.com/bitcoin/bitcoin/pull/7507
we can read*

> *This code removes the internal miner which is only useful on Testnet.
> This leaves the internal miner that is useful on RegTest intact.*

With `-gen=1` on the command line or in the configuration file, *in conjunction with `regtest=1`* `bitcoind` will use its built-in miner to search for blocks *in the regtest network*. It is inefficient, does not support pools, and does not use GPUs. It is only left as a reference and for testing, and *has been* removed *from mainnet* completely.

Comment: when i "setgenerate true" in bitcoin-qt console window, and then "gethashespersec" it reports my hashing power, and "getgenerate" returns true, isn't this a proof that it's mining ?

Comment: Yes, but you'll never mine anything with it. It is far too slow.